# 404 with spaces in the urls

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, http-status-code-404

I've realized that Yahoo search doesn't correctly handle spaces in URLs.

When a user click to go to my website page that contains spaces, yahoo replaces them with '+' symbol.

My server doesn't correctly handle '+' instead of ' ', and generate 404 error.

So how can I replace '+' with ' ', using .htaccess?

Comment: Why do the pages have spaces in the URL? I was under the impression that this is bad form for many reasons, including the one you are mentioning...

Comment: Sure, it's bad. But I can't change them. Any suggestions?

Comment: How *does* your server encode spaces? Normally I believe they're encoded as `%20`, but if your server does it differently, it may be why Yahoo is replacing the spaces (it doesn't recognize them as such).

Comment: @Matt Yes, they are encoded as %20 and Google handles them perfectly. Perhaps Yahoo does some conversions. I need to replace '+' with ' '.

Comment: What's the URL of the Yahoo search?

Comment: Something like this http://m.yahoo.com/apple/onesearch?p=key1+key2+key3&pintl=it&pcarrier=&pmcc=222&pmnc=10 ... and the url which Yahoo point to is /some+things+else.html ... Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` sign can be used to URL encode a space. It's been a part of the standard for ages and Apache 2 definitely knows how to decode a `+` to a space. What may be happening is the `+` is getting encoded itself as `%2B`, and you can change them to spaces using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1\ $2 [L]
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would fit that into something like this:
    RewriteRule ^client/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?client=$1 [L]